# transfer parameter to next request

Tags: jsf, request, parameters

I have a situation where clicking a link in one column on the datatable opens  A update FORM in the same page. The problem is when I hit the submit button for update, the render is set to false again of that update panel which was previously set true by parameter passed clicking the link.

I tried htmlhiddenInput and did setValue and getvalue but the value is lost. Is there any way I can save that parameter send from link, when clicked, even after submitting the form.
I achieved it doing session but I dont wanna use session.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on JSF 2.0, declare the bean `@ViewScoped`. If you're yet on JSF 1.x, then install [Tomahawk](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/) and use [`<t:saveState>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tagdoc/t_saveState.html) to retain the bean property or even the entire bean in the subsequent request. E.g.

```
<t:saveState value="#{bean.renderTable}" />
```

or

```
<t:saveState value="#{bean}" />
```

Comment: I just want the boolean property which was set true by clicking link off update panel to be set true like before not the whole bean while submitting the form to update. Right now , when i click submit , the panel render proterty is getting false and i am not able to update.

Comment: Is that the only Solution ? If possible I would like to go for another alternative.